# Index and Search Archive node database for method hash

Tags: contract-deployment, hash, database, archive-node, method

I want to find similar method hashes, either from contract bytecode or transaction hashes (which in theory are the same because the contract bytecode comes from a contract creation transaction)

I have an archive node with all states. Is there a library with GUI and API and Command line access that lets me do these kinds of queries?

I would prefer to do everything offline, but an online service that uses their own database can be considered too

Comment: might be easier for me to make my own parsing script.... just hoping something more refined existed already

Comment: if you just  need method signatures and transaction hashes then you don't need archival node, simple full node will be enough. Just scan all transactions and the first 4 bytes of the tx.Data() is the method signature, the transaction hash is also there

Comment: @Nulik do you know of a service that will parse and maintain a database for me? or efficiently query the one I already have?

Comment: Dune Analytics ////

Comment: @Nulik I looked there before posting this question, I couldn't figure out how to look for method hashes there, it seems setup to only look for invocations of a specific contract, not whether other contracts or similar methods exist at all!

Comment: I dont use Dune Analytics but I know they are collecting data from traces, so they have all the inputs of all contracts, even between calls (i.e. internal transactions) , so maybe you couldn't find it or maybe this is only for paid members, but they do have it